# How do I prevent losing contrast when compositing semi-transparent images?

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency

I have a scene with an object and a mirror object, simulating a mirror floor. If I fully composite the image and save it with a white background from blender, the mirror image looses a lot of contrast and detail. However, if I save it as a transparent image and add a white background in Photoshop, is is much clearer. How can I get this result straight out of Blender?

My .blend: https://www.dropbox.com/s/38xzr2y717cjygk/mirror_trans01.blend?dl=0

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could the problem have to do with Gamma and how blender treats grey values? It seems like the dark greys are reduced a lot more than the midtones.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a better result by using the Mix node's Multiply blend mode instead of the Alpha Over node.

[image: Result]

Here's the node setup (you first need to create a unified mask to use as a factor for the mix node):
[image: Node setup]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is quite right either. Your multiply version is much too dark, since you are adding the main alpha to the full mirror alpha, rather than a somewhat translucent alpha. On the other hand, if the alpha is reduced to 0.7, you get the exact same result as the alpha-over.